# Invalid field 'subprograms' while parsing LLVM-IR generated by Rust

Tags: rust, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm getting "invalid field 'subprograms'" when parsing LLVM-IR generated from Rust. It happens immediately at `!0`.

Code used to parse:

```
MemoryBuffer* buf = MemoryBuffer::getMemBuffer(StringRef(fC)).release();
SMDiagnostic err;
LLVMContext *Context=new LLVMContext();
Module* module = parseIR(buf->getMemBufferRef(), err, *Context).release();
if(!module){
    NSString* errorMsg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ at line:%@ col:%@\n>>%@",[NSString stringWithCString:err.getMessage().str().c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], @(err.getLineNo()), @(err.getColumnNo()), [NSString stringWithCString:err.getLineContents().str().c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSError* error=[[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:errorMsg code:-1 userInfo:nil];
    //Deal with NSError later
}
DebugInfoFinder* dif = new DebugInfoFinder();
dif->processModule(*module);
```

Where it happens:

```
!0 = distinct !DICompileUnit(language: 36864, file: !1, producer: "rustc version 1.7.0 (a5d1e7a59 2016-02-29)", isOptimized: true, runtimeVersion: 0, emissionKind: 1, enums: !2, retainedTypes: !10, subprograms: !29)
```

The reference is just an array of references to subprograms as expected:

```
!29 = !{!30, !47, !55, !65, !77, !83, !92, !99, !113, !114}
!30 = !DISubprogram(name: "main", linkageName: "_ZN8fizzbuzz4mainE", scope: !32, file: !31, line: 3, type: !33, isLocal: true, isDefinition: true, scopeLine: 3, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, isOptimized: true, function: void ()* @_ZN4main20hbe8861d85740ed2deaaE, templateParams: !35, variables: !36)
```

I think the IR code looks OK; could this be an issue with the LLVM version used by Rust vs. the one used by the llvm-ir parsing snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were breaking changes in debug metadata format recently.

See http://llvm.org/PR27284 for more information

Comment: This bug ticket is from 2015. I've tried with the latest stable rust version and it still happens, so does it mean that rust still uses an older version of llvm?

Comment: @LeonardoMarques Rust is open source, so you can just browse [the repository](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust) to see what version of LLVM they have. In this case, Rust has a [fork of LLVM](https://github.com/rust-lang/llvm) with small changes that haven't been upstreamed yet. This work is kept in various [branches](https://github.com/rust-lang/llvm/branches). From my nightly build of Rust from 2016-05-03, `llc` self-identifies as LLVM 3.8.0.